# javafx: Toggle multiple CheckBoxTableCell-Checkboxes at once

Tags: javafx, checkbox, tablecolumn

### **My Goal**

I have an editable table with a boolean column where one can check or uncheck the containing checkboxes and a multiple row selection policy. I would like my table to automatically toggle all checkboxes of all selected rows as soon as i check or uncheck one.
Don't know if you get the point :D I mean:

1. I select multiple rows
2. I check or uncheck the checkbox of one of those selected rows
3. All other rows's checkboxes get automatically checked or unchecked

Now it should be clear ;)

### **My Question**

(I'm new to JavaFX! I've already done the same thing I'm asking for with AWT/SWING, but am not able to get it working with JavaFX)

Is there similar already built in JavaFX? If not, what is the best aproch to get to my goal?

### **What I've done so far**

I've found out, that you can listen for a change event by setting a CheckBoxTableCell-Callback to the desired Column's CellFactory. I did it like so:

```
TableColumn<FileSelection, Boolean> selectedColumn = new TableColumn<>("Sel");
selectedColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("selected"));
selectedColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(rowidx -> {
    if (tblVideoFiles.getSelectionModel().isSelected(rowidx)) {
        tblVideoFiles.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().forEach(item -> {
            if (!item.getFile().equals(tblVideoFiles.getItems().get(rowidx).getFile())) {
                item.selectedProperty().set(!item.selectedProperty().get());
             }
         });
     }
     return fileList.get(rowidx).selectedProperty();
}));
```

The problem here: As soon as a checkbox gets changed, it toggels itself, resulting in a toggle-loop of checking and unchecking itself :D
How can I stop this?

Comment: [mcve] please .. ;)

Comment: @kleopatra sorry, you are right. I should've provided the Item-Class and at least the app structure with the table. Actually James_D provided everything exactly as I should've done. So do you think it is necessary to update my question? If yes, I do it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is best done directly through the model/selection model, rather than through the cell factory. Here's one approach. The basic idea is:

1. Create an observable list that has an *extractor* mapping to the property of the table items representing whether or not that item is selected (in the sense of the check box in the table)
2. Use a listener on the table's selected items to ensure the list created in step 1 always contains the items that are selected in the table
3. Add a listener to the list created in step 1 that listens for updates; i.e. changes in the properties representing whether the items are checked via the check box.
4. If a table-selected item's checked property changes, update all the selected item's checked properties to match. Set a flag ensuring that those changes are ignored by the listener.

Here's a quick example. First a simple table model class:

```
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Item {
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final BooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    
    public Item(String name) {
        setName(name);
        setSelected(false);
    }
    
    public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return this.name;
    }
    
    public final String getName() {
        return this.nameProperty().get();
    }
    
    public final void setName(final String name) {
        this.nameProperty().set(name);
    }
    
    public final BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
        return this.selected;
    }
    
    public final boolean isSelected() {
        return this.selectedProperty().get();
    }
    
    public final void setSelected(final boolean selected) {
        this.selectedProperty().set(selected);
    }
    
}
```

and then a sample app:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Item, String> itemCol = new TableColumn<>("Item");
        itemCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
        table.getColumns().add(itemCol);

        TableColumn<Item, Boolean> selectedCol = new TableColumn<>("Select");
        selectedCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().selectedProperty());

        selectedCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(selectedCol));

        table.getColumns().add(selectedCol);

        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        // observable list of items that fires updates when the selectedProperty of
        // any item in the list changes:
        ObservableList<Item> selectionList = FXCollections
                .observableArrayList(item -> new Observable[] { item.selectedProperty() });

        // bind contents to items selected in the table:
        table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(
                (Change<? extends Item> c) -> selectionList.setAll(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));

        // add listener so that any updates in the selection list are propagated to all
        // elements:
        selectionList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Item>() {

            private boolean processingChange = false;

            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends Item> c) {
                if (!processingChange) {
                    while (c.next()) {
                        if (c.wasUpdated() && c.getTo() - c.getFrom() == 1) {
                            boolean selectedVal = c.getList().get(c.getFrom()).isSelected();
                            processingChange = true;
                            table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()
                                    .forEach(item -> item.setSelected(selectedVal));
                            processingChange = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            table.getItems().add(new Item("Item " + i));
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(table));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Note that there's an (annoying) rule that observable lists should not be changed while a change is being processed (e.g. by a listener). I'm not sure if this completely obeys that rule, as it changes the properties of an observable list which are part of the extractor, while a listener is processing those changes. I *think* the rule only applies to adding/removing elements, not to updating them, and this code seems to work. However, you might want a hack-around that wraps the code that updates the selected items in a `Platform.runLater(...)` to ensure compliance with this rule:

```
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends Item> c) {
            if (!processingChange) {
                while (c.next()) {
                    if (c.wasUpdated() && c.getTo() - c.getFrom() == 1) {
                        boolean selectedVal = c.getList().get(c.getFrom()).isSelected();
                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            processingChange = true;
                            table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()
                                .forEach(item -> item.setSelected(selectedVal));
                            processingChange = false;
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: hmm .. _rule only applies to adding/removing elements_ good point (don't know and the spec is not really clear) An alternative approach might be not to use  a list at all: instead extend the CheckBoxTableCell and set an action to the checkBox that does the synch's the selectedProperty of all selectedItems. Conceptually, that would be where the solutions belongs, IMO: do something when the checkbox is is clicked vs. when the selected property of an item that's also contained in the selectedItems changes (depends on actual requirements though, the question is not entirely clear ;)

Comment: flashed out the idea in an answer, just a poc :)

Comment: Ok this helped a lot. Thanks to both of you.
I got the point and do now understand why it works with your code but not with mine... Actually you are not using a list to fill out the table. You only have a temp (observable) list to set the items "selected", while I was filling up the observable list with my items, then I was passing the entire list to my table and finally I was trying to update the list (and the table) by setting my items "selected", which is all unnecessary work!
So eventually I used the eventlistener, which I personally prefer over extending the CheckBoxTableCell :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to keeping a copy of selectedItems and sync'ing both (in the contraints of listChange/Listener api) as outlined in [James' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63525632/203657), is to move the responsibility into an action handler of the checkBox of a custom extension of CheckBoxTableCell.

That's not without nuisance either, because the checkBox itself not directly accessible. Which can be overcome with a little trick (beware: using implemenation knowledge in that we expect the checkBox as graphic of the cell!): listen to the graphic property of the cell and register the action the first time its value is not null (and de-register the property listener again).

Below is an example on how to make such a custom cell re-usable:

- the cell is configured with a consumer (parameterized on a TableCell) that carries out the actual workload depending on the state of the passed-in cell
- on instantiation, the cell wraps an action handler around the consumer: the action simply messages the consumer, passing the cell as parameter
- (the trick: on first invalidation of the graphic property, the action handler is set the checkBox)

The behavior implemented here differs from James' solution in that it only updates the item's selected property of the other selectedItems if a checkBox in a selected row fires (and not when programatically changing the property). Which to use depends on requirements.

The custom cell:

```
public class ActionableCheckBoxTableCell<S, T> extends CheckBoxTableCell<S, T> {
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> action;
    InvalidationListener installer;
    
    public ActionableCheckBoxTableCell(Consumer<TableCell<S, T>> cellConsumer) {
        action = ev -> {
            cellConsumer.accept(this);
        };
        registerActionInstaller();
    }
    
    /**
     * Trick to set the action on checkBox (private in super).
     */
    protected void registerActionInstaller() {
        installer = ov -> {
            if (getGraphic() != null) {
                ((ButtonBase) getGraphic()).setOnAction(action);
                graphicProperty().removeListener(installer);
            }
        };
        graphicProperty().addListener(installer);
    }
}
```

Example how to use (hijacking James' solution - just replace the list wiring by setting the custom cell factory instead of core cell factory):

```
Consumer<TableCell<Item, Boolean>> cellConsumer = cell -> {
    TableView<Item> tv = cell.getTableView();
    Item rowItem = tv.getItems().get(cell.getIndex());
    if (!tv.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().contains(rowItem)) return;
    tv.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().forEach(item -> item.setSelected(rowItem.isSelected()));
};
selectedCol.setCellFactory(cc -> new ActionableCheckBoxTableCell<>(cellConsumer));
```

Comment: You get an upvote as well, since your solution is pretty clever. Eventually I prefered to use the listener proposed by @James_D, just because I want to isolate the tools and items i'm just learning to use. I'm working with tables and listeners and that's enough for now. :P All the graphics stuff will be something I will look into, as soon as I'm well up with the basics ;)